# C# format a string

Tags: c#, string, format

I have a String that looks like

```
4/2/2012 12:00 AM
12/30/1899 10:00 AM
```

I want to format the strings so the first date/time stamp looks like

> 4/2/2012

The second should look like

> 10:00 AM

SHould I use the whitespace as a means to split the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For complete string -->

```
string s= DateTime.Parse("4/2/2012 12:00 AM").ToString("d/M/yyyy hh:mm tt");
```

For separated strings -->

```
string date=DateTime.Parse("4/2/2012 12:00 AM").ToString("d/M/yyyy");
string time = DateTime.Parse("4/2/2012 12:00 AM").ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

Comment: Worth looking at `DateTime.TryParse` also - nice if the input strings are not guaranteed to be properly formatted.  Returns true if the parse was successful.

Comment: string date=DateTime.Parse("4/2/2012 12:00 AM").ToString("d/M/YYYY"); should be string date=DateTime.Parse("4/2/2012 12:00 AM").ToString("d/M/yyyy");

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)
Just add `.Tostring("")` and between the `""` you add the pattern, as shown at the site

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

use the following function:

```
     string dstr = "4/2/2012 12:00";        
     DateTime dtime=Convert.ToDateTime(dstr )
     string dt1 = dtime.ToShortDateString();//to get the date
     string dt2 = dtime.ToShortTimeString();//to get the time
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse("4/2/2012 12:00 AM",dt))
{
  String Result = "";
  if (DateTime.Date > DateTime.MinValue)
    Result = dateTime.ToString("d/M/YYYY");
  if (DateTime.TimeOfDay > TimeSpan.MinValue)
    Result += dateTime.ToString("hh:mm tt");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime foo = DateTime.Parse("4/2/2012 12:00 AM");
string date = foo.ToShortDateString();
string time = foo.ToShortTimeString();
```